# Extract string of "length x breadth" into different arrays

Tags: arrays, scala, collections, scala-collections

I have a string with with multiple `length` and `breadth` in the format `length x breadth` separated by commas like

`300x250, 720x220, 560x80`

I will like to convert this into two separate arrays one containing only length and another only breadth.

Expected output

`length = Array(300,720, 560)`

`breadth = Array(250, 220, 80)`

Any novel way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `unzip` over tupled values, as follows,

```
val dims = "300x250, 720x220, 560x80"

dims.split("\\W+").map { 
  s => val Array(a,b,_*) = s.split("x") 
       (a.toInt,b.toInt) }.unzip
```

Note the first `split` fetches words without need for trimming additional blank characters. In the second `split` we extract the first and second elements of the resulting `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
scala> "300x250, 720x220, 560x80"
res0: String = 300x250, 720x220, 560x80

scala> res0.split(", ").map(_.split("x")(0).toInt)
res1: Array[Int] = Array(300, 720, 560)

scala> res0.split(", ").map(_.split("x")(1).toInt)
res2: Array[Int] = Array(250, 220, 80)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val str = "300x250, 720x220, 560x80"
val regex = "(\\d+)x(\\d+)".r
val result = for {
  pair <- str.split(",\\s+").toList
  m <- regex.findAllMatchIn(pair)
} yield (m.group(1).toInt, m.group(2).toInt)

val (length, breadth) = result.unzip
```